# Getting statistics for nodes from a regression tree in the party pagckage

Tags: r, tree, party

I am using the `party` package in R.

I would like to get various statistics (mean, median, etc) from various nodes of the resultant tree, but I cannot see how to do this. For example

```
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, 
                   controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
airct
plot(airct)
```

results in a tree with 4 terminal nodes. How would I get the mean airquality for each of those nodes?

Comment: You want to display vector for each node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surprisingly harder than I thought. Try something like this:

```
a <- by(airq,where(airct),colMeans) #or whatever function you desire for colMeans
a
a$"3" #access at node three
a[["3"]] #same thing
```

You might find some other useful examples with `` ?`BinaryTree-class` ``.

Comment: Thanks!  I am glad, in a way, that it wasn't simple.  I thought it would be.

Answer (score 7):

I can't get which variable of the node is the airquality. But I show you here how to customize your tree plot:

```
innerWeights <- function(node){
  grid.circle(gp = gpar(fill = "White", col = 1))
  mainlab <- node$psplit$variableName
  label   <- paste(mainlab,paste('prediction=',round(node$prediction,2) ,sep= ''),sep= '\n')
  grid.text( label= label,gp = gpar(col='red'))
}

plot(airct, inner_panel = innerWeights)
```

[image]

**Edit to get statistics by node**

library(gridExtra)

```
innerWeights <- function(node){
  dat <- round_any(node$criterion$statistic,0.01)
  grid.table(t(dat))
}
plot(airct, inner_panel = innerWeights)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How to get there if you are lost in R-space (and the documentation does not help you immediately)

First, try `str(airct)`: The output is a bit lengthy, since the results are complex, but for easier cases, e.g. t-test, this is all you need.

Since `print(airct)` or simply `airct` gives quite useful info, how does print work? Try `class(airct)` or check the documentation: The result if of class `BinaryTree`.

Ok, we could have seen this from the docs, and in this case the information on the BinaryTree page is good enough (see the examples on that page.)

But assume the author was lazy: the try  `getAnywhere(print.BinaryTree)`. On the top you find `y<-x@responses`: So try  `airct@responses` next

Comment: thanks for this; I like the expression "lost in R-space" !

But I did look at the documentation and I don't see how to get what I want.  And `airct@responses` also gives a lot of output and I don't see how to tell which one is which or how to extract what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using the `dplyr` package.

First get which node each observation belongs to and store it in the dataframe.

```
airq$node <- where(airct)
```

Then use `group_by` to group the observations by node, and use `summarise` to calculate the mean of the Ozone measurement. You can swap `mean` out for whatever summary statistic function you like.

```
airq %>% group_by(node) %>% summarise(avg=mean(Ozone))
```

Which gives the following results.

```
    node     avg
   (int)    (dbl)
1     3 55.60000
2     5 18.47917
3     6 31.14286
4     8 81.63333
5     9 48.71429
```